# C# RegEx: How to match a string inside the middle words only of a text line?

Tags: c#, regex, text-editor

Using C# RegEx, I need to to match a string "123" inside middle words only of a text line "123xxx123 123 123xxx  xxx123xxx xxx123 123xxx123".

It should match only the inner "123"s, not in the first nor in last word:
"123xxx123 [123] [123]xxx  xxx[123]xxx xxx[123] 123xxx123".

I tried negative lookahead/lookbehind to no avail.

Basically, I need to support a Find utility with options for finding matches (could multi-word) equal to or within starting words, middle words, final words, anywhere in a line.

```
    string pattern_empty_line = @"(" + @"^$" + @")";
    string pattern_whole_line = @"(" + @"^" + text + @"$" + @")";

    string pattern_whole_word = @"(" + @"\b" + text + @"\b" + @")";
    string pattern_prefix = @"(" + @"\S+?" + text + @")";
    string pattern_suffix = @"(" + text + @"\S+?" + @")";
    string pattern_prefix_and_suffix = @"(" + @"\S+?" + text + @"\S+?" + @")";

    // Any Wordness
    string pattern_anywordness_start = @"(" + pattern_whole_line + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"^" + pattern_whole_word + @")" + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"^" + pattern_prefix + @")" + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"^" + pattern_suffix + @")" + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"^" + pattern_prefix_and_suffix + @")"
                                     + @")";
    string pattern_anywordness_end = @"(" + pattern_whole_line + "|"
                                          + @"(" + pattern_whole_word + @"$" + @")" + "|"
                                          + @"(" + pattern_prefix + @"$" + @")" + "|"
                                          + @"(" + pattern_suffix + @"$" + @")" + "|"
                                          + @"(" + pattern_prefix_and_suffix + @"$" + @")"
                                   + @")";
    string pattern_anywordness_not_middle = @"(" + pattern_whole_line + "|" + pattern_anywordness_start + "|" + pattern_anywordness_end + @")";
    string pattern_anywordness_middle = @"(" + @"\b" + @".*" + text + @".*" + @"\b" + @")";
    string pattern_anywordness_anywhere = @"(" + text + @")";

    // Part of word
    string pattern_partword_start = @"(" + pattern_prefix + "|" + @"^" + pattern_prefix_and_suffix + @")";
    string pattern_partword_middle = @"(" + @"(?<!^)" + pattern_prefix_and_suffix + @"(?!$)" + @")";
    string pattern_partword_end = @"(" + pattern_prefix_and_suffix + @"$" + pattern_suffix + "|" + @")";
    string pattern_partword_anywhere = @"(" + pattern_partword_start + "|" + pattern_partword_middle + "|" + pattern_partword_end + @")";

    // Whole word
    string pattern_wholeword_start = @"(" + pattern_whole_line + "|" + @"^" + text + @"\b" + @")";
    string pattern_wholeword_middle = @"(" + pattern_whole_line + "|" + @"(?<!^)" + @"\b" + text + @"\b" + @"(?!$)" + @")";
    string pattern_wholeword_end = @"(" + pattern_whole_line + "|" + @"\b" + text + @"$" + @")";
    string pattern_wholeword_anywhere = @"(" + pattern_wholeword_start + "|" + pattern_wholeword_middle + "|" + pattern_wholeword_end + @")";
```

I was able to match all except middle words and was even able to match inside "NOT middle words" (see code above). It would be nice to find matches in "NOT starting words" and "NOT final words".

Also the desired match could be a multi-word in itself so please take this into account.

Comment: I know it's stupid, but why not just do sth like 'string.Split()` then drop first and last words, do the match, and then add them back in if you need it?

Comment: Of course that would be the first thing I would do but this is a method that takes conditions (location_in_line, location_in_word, ...) and returns a RegEx pattern that I then use elsewhere to run against a file with 1000s of lines.

Comment: Doing things like `pattern_empty_line` and `pattern_whole_line` with regex is overkill. In fact, I don't see an attempt to escape the text in the latter so it could be used, intentionally or not, to [cause problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) with your program.

Comment: Full application is open-source so feel free to browse the whole C# code at https://github.com/heliwave/QuranCode. The above code extract can be found in 
string BuildPattern(...) Server\Server.cs

If you can suggest improvements to the code please do so too. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve my own question.

I just needed to add "\s" before and after my search pattern for whole words, prefixed words, suffixed word or prefixed and suffixed words.

```
    string pattern_anywordness_middle = @"(" + pattern_whole_line + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"\s" + pattern_whole_word + @"\s" + @")" + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"\s" + pattern_prefix + @"\s" + @")" + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"\s" + pattern_suffix + @"\s" + @")" + "|"
                                            + @"(" + @"\s" + pattern_prefix_and_suffix + @"\s" + @")"
                                      + @")";
```